# IK/Spline IK Armature Controllers binding to respective bone

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I've created a rig with IK Controllers for the hands/feet and a Spline IK system for the tail, both of which work rather well for my purposes.  However, I want to improve their functionality by binding them to their respective bones so that their custom shapes rotate appropriately with the bones and cannot slide away from the armature.

Is it possible to bind the IK controllers to the ankles/wrists and and to bind the spline IK hooks so they cannot slide along the tail?